# Differential Equations Methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it possible to solve this first-order O.D.E using the separable equations method? I tried solving it using exact equations and integrating factors to make the equation exact but I got stuck once I got the integrating factor and multiplied it with the original equation the new M and N become too complicated to work with!

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= x-1+xy-y $$

Any help?

Comment: Factor the expression on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the problem as $\frac{dy}{dx} = (x-1)(y+1)$ and can then use separation of variables (I will write $y'$ for $\frac{dy}{dx}$) to get
$$\frac{y'}{y+1} = x-1$$
Then integrating with respect to $x$ gives
$$\ln(y+1) = \frac 12 x^2-x + c$$
And that gives
$$y = ce^{\frac{x^2}{2}-x}-1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=x+xy-1-y=(x-1)(1+y)
$$
hence
$$
\frac{y'}{1+y}=x-1
$$
or
$$
\ln(1+y)=\frac{x^2}{2}-x+c
$$